# Single Controller for multiple html section and data from ajax request angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to show two section of my html page with same json data, i don't want to wrap both in same controller as it is positioned in different areas.  I have implemented that concept successfully by using local json data in "angular service" see the demo

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="nameCtrl">
    <a href="#" ng-click="addName();">Add New</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="removeName();">Remove First</a>
    <ul id="first" class="navigation">
        <li ng-repeat="myname in mynames">{{myname.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    Lot of things in between
</div>

<ul id="second" class="popup" ng-controller="nameCtrl">
       <li ng-repeat="myname in mynames">{{myname.name}}</li>        
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
    var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);


testApp.service('nameService', function($http) {
    var me = this;

    me.mynames = [
        {
            "name": "Funny1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Funny2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Funny3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Funny4"
        }
    ];

    //How to do
    /*this.getNavTools = function(){
        return $http.get('http://localhost/data/name.json').then(function(result) {
            me.mynames    = result.mynames;
            return result.data;
        });
    };*/



    this.addName = function() {
        me.mynames.push({
            "name": "New Name"
        });
    };


    this.removeName = function() {
            me.mynames.pop();
    };

});

testApp.controller('nameCtrl', function ($scope, nameService) {

    $scope.mynames        =   nameService.mynames;


    $scope.$watch(
        function(){ return nameService },

        function(newVal) {
            $scope.mynames          =  newVal.mynames;
        }
    )

    $scope.addName = function() {
        nameService.addName();
    }



    $scope.removeName = function() {
        nameService.removeName();
    }

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/z6fEf/4/)

Next thing i want to do is to make a http request to json file and load my two section with data, and if  i add or remove it should reflect in both areas.

Any pointers or exisisitng demo will be much helpful.

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you uncomment the commented method getNavTools. You just need to abstract the static mynames array you created to call the getNavTools method.

Comment: I have updated the  demo with http request, what happens now is  only the last html section is only updated if i click add or remove link

jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/z6fEf/5/

Comment: @user538776 I answered you question based on your updated demo, check it out. And please update your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why only one `ngRepeat` is updating is because they are bound to two different arrays.

How could it happen? It's because that you have called `getNavTools()` twice, and in each call, you have replaced `mynames` with a *new* array! Eventually, the `addName()` and `removeName()` are working on the last assigned array of `mynames`, so you're seeing the problem.

I have the fix for you:

```
testApp.service('nameService', function($http) {
    var me = this;
    me.mynames = []; // me.mynames should not be replaced by new result

    this.getNavTools = function(){
        return $http.post('/echo/json/', { data: data }).then(function(result) {
            var myname_json = JSON.parse(result.config.data.data.json);
            angular.copy(myname_json, me.mynames); // update mynames, not replace it
            return me.mynames;
        });
    };

    this.addName = function() {
        me.mynames.push({
            "name": "New Name"
        });
    };


    this.removeName = function() {
        me.mynames.pop();
    };
});

testApp.controller('nameCtrl', function ($scope, nameService) {

    // $scope.mynames        =   nameService.mynames; // remove, not needed

    nameService.getNavTools().then(function() {
        $scope.mynames = nameService.mynames;
    });

    /* Remove, not needed
    $scope.$watch(
        function(){ return nameService },

        function(newVal) {
            $scope.mynames          =  newVal.mynames;
        }
    );
    */

    $scope.addName = function() {
        nameService.addName();
    };

    $scope.removeName = function() {
        nameService.removeName();
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6fEf/9/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to put the data in a parent scope (maybe in $rootScope) it will trigger the both views ,And you don't need to $watch here..

```
 $rootScope.mynames        =   nameService.mynames;
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6fEf/8/)

Comment: Try to limit polluting the $rootScope. In your case I would just create another controller and use the same service. A controller should really just be in charge of a component on your page.

Comment: yeah That's true, may be he could have a top level controller covering both HTML views...